# How to remove words with hyperlinks from a string in PHP?

Tags: php

I need some help with removing words that contains hyperlinks in PHP. Example:

```
I was here dumb*
```

*has hyperlink

I want it to be like this:

```
I was here
```

without `dumb`

Can someone help me on this?
Thanks.

**Edit**:

I am gonna load "[This page](http://bit.ly/iinHmF)" and then remove all words containing hyperlinks. Example: "LYSSNA, BILD SVENSKA / BILD FINSKA"

Comment: You mean you have a string like `I was here <a href="..">dumb</a>` ?

Comment: I am gonna load "bit.ly/iinHmF"; and then remove all words containing hyperlinks. Example: "LYSSNA, BILD SVENSKA / BILD FINSKA"

Answer (score 3):

```
function findAndReplace($arr) {
    return '<strong>'.$arr[1].'</strong>';
}

$inputText = 'Why use <a href="#"  style="padding-left:5px"> PHP </a>?';
echo "<br />Input is: <br />";
echo $inputText;

$returnText = preg_replace_callback('@<a(?:.*)>(.*)</a>@isU', 'findAndReplace', $inputText);

echo "<br /><br />Output will be: <br />";
echo $returnText;
```

Source: http://php-opensource-help.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-to-remove-hyperlink-from-string.html

**EDIT**

Since you edited your original post:
Try:

```
$new_string=preg_replace ("/<a.*>/i","",$string);
```

Comment: I think there should be used lazy matching `.*?` otherwise it will not work with two hyperlinks.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work:

`$string_without_hyperlinks = preg_replace('/<a\s.*?>.*?<\/a>/s', '', $string);`